# Find an item using reduce() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. I want to loop trough that array and to check if an item match a criteria, using reduce method from javascript:

```js
const arr = [{
    value: 'test',
    label: 'Test'
  },
  {
    value: 'car',
    label: 'Car'
  },
]


const res = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.value) {
    acc.push({
    element: item.label,
    id: item.value,
    })
  }
  if(item.value !== 'car') {
    acc.push({element: 'here', id: 'here'})
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Using `if(item.value !== 'car') { acc.push({element: 'here', id: 'here'}) }` i try to inspect if in my list is not at all a  value that is not equal with 'car', then add that object, but it adds even if in the list exists `car` title, but what i want to achieve is to see if in the array is not any item that is equal with `car`, only after that to add that object. How to achieve that without using `find()` but only reduce()? 
 Examples: 1. if i check the title `car` then that object should not be added . 2. If i check the title 'unknown', then that object should be added.

Comment: Your `if (item.value)` condition is pushing any object that has a *truthy* value into your `acc` array. Just change it to `item.value !== 'car'` and remove this second `if` unless you want to push the object `{element: 'here', id: 'here'}` for every item that does not have title `'car'`

Comment: `using find() but only reduce()`  Logically what your after wouldn't be find anyway, did you mean `filter()`?..  ps, if you did mean find reduce is going to give you less performance, as find returns early on first found item..

Comment: What you want to do is unclear to me, maybe giving the expected output of your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you only need to filter by some elements (not car elements). This way, you don't need to use "reducer", you can use "filter". Please, check the code below:

```js
const arr = [{
    value: 'test',
    label: 'Test'
  },
  {
    value: 'car',
    label: 'Car'
  },
];

// Using filter (recommended in your case)
// const notCarElements = arr.filter(elem => elem.value !== 'car');

// Using reducer
const notCarElements = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.value === 'car') return acc;
  acc.push(item);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(notCarElements);
```

Comment: but how to check `item.value !== 'unknown value'` and only if that value  does not exits in the entire array, then add `acc.push({element: 'not in the list', id: 'not in the list'})`?